# Whats wrong with this Telerik grid query

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, telerik-grid, telerik-mvc

I have a Telerik grid query. The grid with delete action is working fine in FF and Crome. But in IE showing error 500. I put up break point at the starting point of action method. But its not reaching the action at all. Please tell me what's wrong with this query.

**Query**

```
    @(Html.Telerik().Grid<Vibrant.Areas.ItemControl.Models.ViewModel>()
                                    .Name("Temp").ClientEvents(e => e.OnLoad("SetFilterPosition").OnDataBinding("Grid_onDataBinding").OnRowDataBound("RowBound").OnDataBound("onDataBound"))
                                                                                                                                    .DataKeys(d => { d.Add(a => a.Itemid).RouteKey("Id"); d.Add(a => a.CurrItemNo).RouteKey("ItemNo"); d.Add(a => a.CurrStatus).RouteKey("Status"); d.Add(a => a.CurrLocation).RouteKey("Location"); d.Add(a => a.CurrStart).RouteKey("Start"); d.Add(a => a.CurrEnd).RouteKey("End"); d.Add(a => a.Option).RouteKey("Option"); })
                                                                                                                    .ToolBar(commands => commands.Position(GridToolBarPosition.Bottom)
                        .Custom().ButtonType(GridButtonType.Text)
                            .HtmlAttributes(new { id = "export" })
                            .Text("Export to Excel")
                                                    .Action("ExportExcel", "WeedItem", new { page = 1, orderBy = "~", filter = "~" }))
    .Columns(columns =>
    {
        columns.Bound(o => o.INo).Title("Item No");
        columns.Bound(o => o.BTags).Title("Title");
        columns.Bound(o => o.Sid).Title("Status");
        //columns.Bound(o => o.Option).Title("Record Status");
        columns.Command(commands =>
        {
            commands.Delete();

        }).Width(80).Title("Action");
    })

                      .Pageable(paging =>
                    paging.PageSize(10)
                              .Style(GridPagerStyles.NextPreviousAndDropDown | GridPagerStyles.Numeric)
                                  .Position(GridPagerPosition.Bottom)
                )
            .DataBinding(dataBinding => dataBinding
                                        .Ajax().Select("post", "WeedItem").Delete("DeleteTempData", "WeedItem"))
   .Sortable()
   .Filterable()
   .Groupable()
    )
```

**Controller**

```
    [GridAction]
    public ActionResult DeleteTempData(int Id)
    {
       var model = ......
                   ...... ;
       return View(new GridModel(model));
    }
```

Thanks

Comment: Use fiddler ot DevTools of IE and see what exactly did the server responded when it says internal error 500.

Answer (score 0):

The view is returned at the end of your action method.  If you cannot hit a debug point at the start of action method, then the problem is not in your view (or grid).  500 is an internal server error, I'd double check the URL you're trying to navigate to and custom errors off in your web.config.

```
<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <customErrors mode="Off"/>
        ...
    </system.web>
    ...
</configuration>
```

Comment: My Config's customErrors mode is now Off only. But still i get the 500 error.

Comment: If you try remove the `[GridAction]` attribute, does that help?  Otherwise your problem appears to be outside of the code posted in your original post.

Comment: Removing [GridAction] results the same error. Grid edit, Custom command are working fine. But delete command throws error.